# How to make Thunderbird obey locale?

Tags: thunderbird, locale

My system locale is en_DK.utf8 and I want ISO-dates (yyyy-mm-dd) everywhere.

```
% locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_DK:en
LC_CTYPE="en_DK.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_DK.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_DK.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_DK.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_DK.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_DK.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_DK.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_DK.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_DK.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_DK.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_DK.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_DK.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_DK.utf8
```

If I start Thunderbird from the command line, the dates are correct. However, when starting it from a menu, the dates are in mm/dd/yyyy-format no matter what I do.

I've tried ConfigDate and QuickLocaleSwitcher, none of them are capable of changing the date-format in Thunderbird if started from a menu. I've also tried setting things in dconf, same result:

```
% dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/time-format "'custom'"
% dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/custom-time-format "'%F %R'"
```

So: How can I force Thunderbird to use the date format I want, even when started from a menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this it appears to be what you want
http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/linux/how-to-change-thunderbirds-date-format-in-date-column
`export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 && thunderbird`
oh and i did test it here

Comment: In KDE4 it is in addition necessary to remove all existing short cuts, for instance in Favorites, because existing short cuts remember the old, wrong behavior. After doing that, it works!